# Slow performance filtering on ntext column on large table

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table that logs user changes with this definition:

```
audit_trail
(
   change_id int identity (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   change_date datetime NOT NULL,
   user_id int NOT NULL,
   record_id int NOT NULL,
   table_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   field_name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
   new_value ntext NULL
)
```

This query runs very slow (15+ minutes) on this table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT record_id
FROM audit_trail
WHERE table_name = 'jobs'
    AND field_name = 'status'
    AND new_value LIKE '157'
```

My table has over 70 million records. This is not a usual query for this table. Normal queries on this table sort by date or search for changes in a date range so I have a clustered index on the `change_date` column. The execution plan for this query shows it doing a clustered index scan. I thought I could improve the performance by adding an nonclustered index on `(table_name, field_name)` but this index was not even used. Any recommendations on improving this query's performance?

Comment: why are you using like with no wildcards in the pattern?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod new_value is an ntext column. You can't use '=' for string comparison.

Comment: Right, I suspect that the performance hit has to do with the ntext column. What is the selectivity of this column? As an experiment, dupp the table with nvarchar instead of ntext, then try query again.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I can try duplicating with an nvarchar, but it's going to take a very long time. And it's not something I can do in the long run. Some of the data in this column is very long and won't fit in a nvarchar column. I was researching setting the "text in row" to ON for this table. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: This really depends on the character of the data in ntext and especially the length. You cannot have text in row greater than 7000 bytes (not characters). However if many entries are three character as above, this may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

```
sp_tableoption N'audit_trail', 'text in row', '1024'
```

You might also consder [full-text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are suggesting 1024 bytes as the limit? I've read that "text in row" can help insert/update/read performance, but I haven't read much about improvements when the column is used in a filter. Any resources on this?

Comment: @invis, no just a round binary number. Read performance is what you want to improve for your query.

Comment: Ok. I'll run some tests soon. I'll let you know if this helps.

Comment: This did end up improving performance by about 60%. I ended up using a limit of 50 bytes. I also had to run "UPDATE audit_trail SET new_value = new_value" to move the text data under the limit into the row. I'm still doing research on the positives and negatives of this, but I think it will help. I may also try adding an indexable truncated new_value column of nvarchar(50) that I can do searches on. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do that, changing nvarchar into varchar will improve the size, and probably the performance of your table.  I also suspect that removing the unnecessary "DISTINCT" will allow the optimizer to use the other indexes.

Comment: I can't change the type of the columns. Hmm.. I'll have to try the query without DISTINCT to see if it makes a difference. It is not unnecessary actually since this query could return the same record more than once.

Comment: I suppose it was simplified for SO, but in your sample, the DISTINCT does not seem necessary.